# How to filter a polymorphic relationship to only return a specific model?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, polymorphism, relationship

I'm having an issue with defining a function to filter a polymorphic relationship and only return a specific model. I'll try to explain below:

Say I have three models: `A`, `B`, and `C`. Model `A` can belong to either of the other two models. Say we're using the polymorphism field name of `recipient`, so on our model `A` database schema we have `recipient_type` and `recipient_id`.

On model `A`, I have a the default function called `recipient`, defined like so:

```
public function recipient()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

However, I want a function called `b()` which will return a relationship so that it can be used with a query builder using the `with()` function. The idea being I can call `$a->b` and it will either return an instance of `B` or null, depending on whether the instance of `A` belongs to and instance of `B`...

Sorry this has been a bit of a mouthful..

Appreciate all the help I can get with this one!
Cheers!

Comment: Doesn't the `A->recipient` return either the `B` or `C` depending on the `recipient_type` for that `A`? Sorry, if I got you wrong!

Answer (score 2):

You can define it like this

Model A  (define [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators))

```
public function recipient()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}

public function bRelation()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(B::class, 'recipient_id', 'id');
}

public function cRelation()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(C::class, 'recipient_id', 'id');
}

public function getBAttribute(){ //define accessor
    if($this->recipient_type == 'App\B') return $this->bRelation;
    return null;
}

public function getCAttribute(){ //define accessor 
    if($this->recipient_type == 'App\C') return $this->cRelation;
    return null;
}
```

Now use it with eager loading

```
$records = A::with('bRelation', 'cRelation')->get();

foreach($records as $a){
   dd($a->b); //it will return you either instance of `B` or `null`
}
```

Comment: Hi rkj,

I'm afraid this doesn't seem to have the desired effect. The belongs to works fine, and retrieves the instance of model `B` which matches the id of the `recipient_id`, but the following where clause is applied on model `B`'s table, not model `A`'s.


We need it to be applied to model `A`'s table

Comment: @PapierMoustachio you are right, i made changes in answer using `accessor`. check it once

Answer (score 1):

Works well with accessors:

```
public function getIssueAttribute()
{
    if($this->commentable_type == 'issues') return $this->commentable;
    return null;
}

public function getProjectAttribute()
{
    if($this->commentable_type == 'projects') return $this->commentable;
    return null;
}

public function commentable()
{
    return $this->morphTo('commentable');
}
```